# Context-aware AJAX call in a modular site

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, content-management-system

**Edit:** I thought about a possible solution, but I made another question as it is very specific: see [AJAX proxy with PHP, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792744/ajax-proxy-is-it-possible)

---

A couple of times I've encountered this problem...

I create sites that have a certain degree of modularity. So, it is possible that there are "components" (think of a rough CMS) which carry their own PHP code, CSS, and JavaScript, all dynamically included. Think about a structure like:

```
{siteroot}/component/datagrid/datagrid.php
{siteroot}/component/datagrid/js/datagrid.js
{siteroot}/component/datagrid/css/datagrid.css
{siteroot}/component/datagrid/ajax/getsomedata.php
```

Now, the question is: **for JavaScript files, and expecially AJAX calls, how do I make them context-aware with the URLs?**
For example, if in `datagrid.js` I want to call `siteroot/component/datagrid/ajax/getsomedata.php` with AJAX I should write (with JQuery):

```
$("#ajax").load("siteroot/component/datagrid/ajax/getsomedata.php");
```

---

**First problem**: `siteroot` changes on different installations. I've managed that by including a general

```
var codeBase = <? echo json_encode(Config::$siteRoot); ?>
```

with PHP on every page, from a Config file that can be easily edited for every installation, so I can do with whatever JavaScript something like:

```
$("#ajax").load(codeBase + "/component/Datagrid/ajax/getsomedata.php");
```

What do you think of this approach?

---

**Second problem**: but I have PHP functions that return to me also the components folder, or the folder of other components. It would be nice to make the **whole** URL dynamic. This would account also for changes in the structure of the component if I want.
The only solution I've found is to use a `.js.php` dynamic Javascript. This is very unelegant, and I have to include all the framework in the JavaScript file, like:

```
<?php
include "../../libs/framework.php"; // get my functions...
$myUrl = Config::$siteRoot . Framework::getComponentAjaxDir("datagrid") . "/getsomedata.php";
?>
$("#ajax").load(<?=json_encode($myUrl)?>);
```

Another side effect is that I have to know **exactly** the `include` the path for `framework.php`... I don't want this so hard-codedin my ".js.php" file.
Any smart solutions about that?

Comment: well as far as this is concerned 'var codeBase = <? echo json_encode(Config::$siteRoot); ?>'
 it isnt that bad but what i do with my ajax calls is that i send "codeBase " aka base_url as parameter to the ajax function. 2ndly correct me if i am wrong but when ever we change the platform we usually tell what is our site root so its kinda hard coded at that part. But yeah your approach is good and you can also try my approach

Comment: @noobie-php Yes but it's better hardcoded in a separate config file that I can change at will. My goal is also to make the "component" part dynamic without resorting to ugly includes (what if I change the component folder structure? I'll have to rewrite the includes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody answered in a suitable way, I answer to myself to provide a solution I've found out that can be useful.
The key to my solution is simple:

1. I create an AJAX proxy at a fixed location in my site structure, so I can use `codeBase` to reference the proxy from JavaScript
2. I call this proxy with two parameters: `plugin` and `action`, which identify a) the plugin folder in which the "real" ajax is and b) the ajax file to use, along with the other params:

   $("#...").load( codeBase + "/main/ajax.php?plugin=Datagrid&action=gettable&otherparams"...)
3. In `ajax.php` I sanitize the parameters, and use `plugin` and `action` to obtain the "real" ajax file:

   {serverRoot}/components/{plugin}/ajax/{action}.php

Then i simply `include` that file in `ajax.php`

Answer (score 1):

To be honest your `problems` are realistic `options` and aren't that bad practice in general quite frankly.

But let's explore this a little further.

What would be the best approach is for you to have 1 main `config.php` file which you can then specify `modules`, i.e. your datagrid etc.

You could store all modules in an array variable like so:

```
$_SITE_PATH = "/var/www/html/";
$_HTTP_PATH = "http://example.com/";

$_MODULES_PATH = $_SITE_PATH."modules/"

$_MODULES = array(
    "datagrid"=>$_MODULES_PATH."datagrid/init.php",
    "something_else"=>$_MODULES_PATH."something_else/init.php"
);
```

Each `module` would have it's own directory with instantiation `init.php` so that it would load all it required to get going.

This way you could code as you liked and when you needed something (preferably in the header state) do something like this.

```
global $_MODULES;
require_once($_MODULES["datagrid"]);
```

Everything will be easily available as and when required without any `variable` path issues later down the line.

Comment: That's ok, I'm familiar with the approach (indeed it can be done without `global`s with a Config class). The problem is for the *client-side* code (JavaScript and AJAX in particular).

Comment: you could provide the main keys you'd need to reference in jQuery perhaps by serializing it into a json object then you wouldn't need to make as much 'code-mess' or have it in plain sight as is. ? Just a thought..